# how to get the function responsible for the rendered variable inside an html file

Tags: magento2

in my case I want to see from where the variable 'options' is rendered , because i want to change some functionality inside the defaut.html file , his path is  :

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

i want to change some functionality but I don't know from where the variable  'options' is called inside the 'default.html' file , is it the controller or block ?

```
 <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 1):

With knockout JS you can access variables and functions of component that is bind with HTML template.

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'some-demo-scope'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "some-demo-scope": {
                    "component": "Somthing/somthing.js",
                    "template": "Template/template.html"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i don't understand how can this help me find from where the variable 'options'  is called? ,

Comment: Basically, the component JS file has all your variables and functions.

Comment: so i need to dump something like 'option' how can i do it